# Mask URL using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-masking

I'm trying to use htaccess to mask a domain with another domain.

For example: My main site is https://example.com hosted on one server, 
and my other site  http://blog.example.com is hosted on different server.

What I want for end result is, when people try to access site https://example.com/blog, the content of http://blog.example.com/ should get displayed on the page, but the URL in the address bar should stay the same as https://example.com/blog

Is there any way to achieve the same?

My Current htaccess is: (Not working)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com\/blog$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,P]
```